# Jest - TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, testing, enzyme, jestjs

Out of nowhere, I'm having an issue when running certain Jest tests:

```
Summary of all failing tests
 FAIL  server/controllers/voice/settings/__tests__/voice.settings.controller.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

      at Runtime._createJestObjectFor (node_modules/jest-runner/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:734:35)
      at handle (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
      at process.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
      at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
      at process.emit (events.js:214:7)
```

I saw that someone had the same problem here (https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5058) but I'm not sure if it ever got resolved. I tried removing node_modules and reinstalling but that didn't fix it. Wondering if anyone else has had the same error before and how it got resolved?

Comment: Can you show us the failing test and an example from another test case that uses `jest.fn` without failing?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in my react app.So i added my jest setup.js file to

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

after that test worked fine

Answer (score 0):

So this error actually came up since I was using node v8.9.3. After downgrading back to v6.11.1, this issue went away.